# Elastic BeanStalk Docker app, writing local files

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a play scala application that I am deploying as a generic docker application via the AWS Elasticbeanstalk console. When I run the application locally, I don't see any issues, so I would think the code is right.
I need to have the ability to

- Write files to local disk
- Run some command line utilities (like ffmpeg) on those files

However, my application does not write to the local disk, nor does it let me execute command line utilities.

```
 val localFile = new File(s"$localFilePath/$siteId/download/${fileName}.raw")
 s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, summary.getKey), localFile)
 val cmd = s"ffmpeg -i ${localFile.getAbsolutePath} -vcodec copy ${localFile.getAbsolutePath}.mp4"
 cmd !;
```

This is my Dockerrun.aws.json file

```
{"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1","Logging": "/opt/docker/logs"}
```

**UPDATE**
Updated my Dockerrun.aws.json file to include the volume mapping

```
{"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1","Logging": "/opt/docker/logs","Volumes":[{"HostDirectory": "/tmp/files","ContainerDirectory": "/tmp/files"}]}
```

The app is now writing local files, but unable to run ffmpeg for some reason.

```
Exception : Cannot run program "ffmpeg": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: By running "locally", do you mean inside a container on your laptop or outside of Docker completely? Also, can you provide more information regarding what is actually happening? Are you getting an exception? Does the code run but you don't see the output files?

Comment: locally = `sbt run` on my laptop (not via Docker)
Not actually getting an exception, it pretends like as if the `s3Client.getObject` downloaded to the localfile , but ffmpeg complains that no input file was found.
When I inspect the EC2 instance, I don't see any files.

Comment: You will not see the files in the EC2 instance if you're not using Docker volumes. Docker containers have their own isolated filesystem. Can you share your Dockerfile to help understand the problem? It might be related to the fact that you're using absolute paths inside a container.

Comment: This is my Dockerrun.aws.json
`{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Logging": "/opt/docker/logs"
}`

Comment: I meant - your **Dockerfile**. This is what is used to build your container image. The **Dockerrun** file is what Beanstalk uses to deploy a container from your Docker image. Do you have a Dockerfile? If so, could you paste it in the original post? If not, how does your code run? From what you pasted as your Dockerrun file, Beanstalk will not know which Docker container to run. See the official documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html#create_deploy_docker_image_dockerfile.

Comment: After some more searching I found that AWS will allow you to specify docker volumes in the Dockerrun.aws.json file. Like so,
`"Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/var/app/mydb",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/etc/mysql"
    }
  ],`
I send all my data to `/tmp/files/...`
Any idea how I may use this for my purposes ?

Comment: Looks like your problem at the moment is not related to the volumes. I'm guessing your code doesn't even run at the moment since I don't see any way for Beanstalk to know what to do with your code. Check the link in my previous comment - it contains info on how to bundle your code before you upload. Sure, you can use Docker volumes to "export" files from the container, however you need to get your code to run first...

Comment: I'm using the single container docker configuration [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html ], which actually does not need a Dockerfile.
The code seems to run fine, and does a bunch of other things that are not related to writing to local disk.

Comment: Actually that did it, I added `"Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/tmp/files",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/tmp/files"
    }` to the Dockerrun.aws.json file

Comment: Cool, glad you solved it. May I ask how Beanstalk knows which Docker image to run if you didn't include a Dockerfile and didn't specify an `image` in the Dockerrun file?

Comment: From the AWS link above 
`A Dockerrun.aws.json file describes how to deploy a Docker container as an Elastic Beanstalk application. This JSON file is specific to Elastic Beanstalk. If your application runs on an image that is available in a hosted repository, you can specify the image in a Dockerrun.aws.json file and omit the Dockerfile.`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @JohananLiebermann
Now that  that problem is fixed. Just can't tell why ffmpeg wont run/can't be found. Is that a Docker thing too ?
I manually installed ffmpeg on the ec2 instance (via wget/tar, and installed it in `/usr/bin` `/bin`. Seems to run just fine from the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - `ffmpeg` can't be found by your application because you installed it on the **host** operating system while your code runs in the **container** operating system. To fix that, install `ffmpeg` in your container by writing a custom [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

## Software Containers

Now, in order to better understand your problem you must understand that software containers are a special kind of *virtualization*. That is, the operating system inside the container is **completely separate** from the host operating system and from other containers on the same machine, be it your laptop or your EC2 instance. Containers *may* share some information with the host OS or with other containers on the same machine, however you need to do explicit operations in order to achieve that (i.e. Docker volumes).

**Docker containers** are a specific type of software containers. Some basic information regarding Docker and containers in general can be found in the official [What is Docker](https://www.docker.com/what-docker) page.

### Containers vs VMs

Containers are a little similar to virtual machines, however in my opinion there are more differences than similarities between the two. They are similar in the sense that they allow you to run multiple applications on the same hardware while each application gets its own, separate, virtual environment. They are different from VMs in the *kind* of virtualization - while an application on a VM shares the same **hardware** with other applications on the same host, an application inside a container shares **both the hardware and the operating system** of the host.

### Code in a Container is Isolated!

Docker containers provide a virtually-separate environment for every application by leveraging [specific capabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC) of the Linux operating system. Each container lives in a virtually-isolated environment, which makes it feel as if it has its own filesystem, networking, process IDs etc. This means that anything that happens inside a container does not affect the host, and vice versa.

Therefore, when working with Docker containers you normally don't do much on the *host*. For example, in your case it would be wrong to install `ffmpeg` on the host and then try to use it from within the container. Even though it's possible, it defeats the whole purpose of using Docker. The correct approach would be to have all your dependencies installed **inside** the container. Not only will it solve your `No such file` problem, it will also allow you to run your container anywhere you like (AWS, GCP, your laptop...) and will always work exactly the same. This kind of portability is unique to containers and is *one of the main reasons* people use containers as it allows you to have a **consistent** behavior of your code since it always runs in exactly the same environment.

### Pack Your Environment With the Code

Another way of looking at it is - when using Docker, you pack your execution environment with the code. This is done in a very efficient and compact way - using a **Dockerfile**. You simply include a Dockerfile in the root directory where your code is. The Dockerfile contains all the instructions which are required for creating the environment your code needs in order to run. In the Dockerfile you install dependencies, copy files, change permissions and do many other things. Then, you build an **image** from which you can launch containers.

Using Dockerfiles also allows you to **version control** your dependencies and provides a nice replacement to configuration management tools like Chef, Ansible and Puppet.

I suggest you take a look at the [official training videos](https://training.docker.com/introduction-to-docker) on the Docker website. They will give you a better understanding of what Docker is and how to work with it.

## Conclusion

To conclude, if you simply want to run your code on Elastic Beanstalk, you don't have to use Docker. You can probably get it to run on Beanstalk's Java environment (though I've never done that myself). However, if you want to Dockerize your application, you would first need to have a better understanding of Docker since working with containers requires **a shift in perspective** that is not always easy to do.